# Dynamic tooltip in JSP using Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, internationalization, ognl, struts-tags

I'm trying to add a tooltip to a series of buttons. The text is dynamic in that it needs a parameter (shows a text with a page number) and is stored in `global.properties`:

```jsp
page.nr.tooltip=Go to page {0}
```

I've tried several things, none of which work:

```jsp
title="<s:text name='page.nr.tooltip'>
        <s:param value='pageNum' />
        </s:text>"
```

I've also tried setting a variable and using that:

```jsp
<s:set var="ttStr" value="<s:text name='page.nr.tooltip'>
        <s:param value='pageNum' />
        </s:text>" />
```

But I can't seem to use it as a tooltip-text either. Tried either of these (and more)

```jsp
value="ttStr"
value="$ttStr"
value="#attr[#ttStr]"
```

which won't display the text.
Any suggestions? Javascript is not possible because the application has to run in browsers with js turned off.
I'm probably missing something really simple...

### EDIT:

Guess I need to clarify a bit:
`pageNum` is a variable I set like this:

```jsp
<s:set var="pageNum" value="..." />
```

and it is valid since I can use it and it has the correct value. I want to add the `pageNum` as a variable to the tooltip-text, something like this:

```jsp
<s:submit type="button" class="..."
   title="<s:text name='page.nr.tooltip'>
             <s:param value='pageNum' />
          </s:text>">
...
```

This will not render the tooltip as "`Go to page 4`" (or whatever value pageNum has). It renders to "`<s:text name='page.nr.tootip' ...`" - in other words the exact text in quotes from the example above.
I know how to set and use variables from the action class - that wouldn't help here though.
The title-attribute doesn't render the value "Go to page " at all. Even if I just write

```jsp
<s:submit type="button" class="..."
       title="<s:text name='page.nr.tooltip'/>"
```

it displays `<s:text name='page.nr.tooltip'/>` as the tooltip text. Surprised this isn't working for me.

Comment: To which tag you put `title` attribute? What is `pageNum`? Where it is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use tag inside another tag attribute. Use `var` attribute of `<s:text>` tag to push value to the value stack. And then use OGNL to get this value in the `title` attribute of the `<s:submit>`.

```
<s:text var="pageTooltip" name="page.nr.tooltip">
    <s:param value="#pageNum"/>
</s:text>

<s:submit type="button" title="%{#pageTooltip}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is from Struts [localization guide](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/localization.html):

> Global Resources (`struts.custom.i18n.resources`) in `struts.properties`
>
> A global resource bundle could be specified programmatically, as well
> as the locale.

You can also set a constant in `struts.xml`

```xml
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="/resources/global"/>
```

The variable `pageNum` should have a getter to return a value for the parameter

```jsp
<s:text name='page.nr.tooltip'>
  <s:param value='pageNum' />
</s:text>
```

This code will render the message text to the out. If you need to set this text to one of Struts tags attribute you should use OGNL. Don't nest Struts2 tags inside attributes.

```jsp
<s:submit type="button" class="..."
   title="%{getText('page.nr.tooltip', {pageNum})}" />
```

To use `getText` the action should implement `TextProvider` that what `ActionSupport` is for. If your action class extends `ActionSupport` then you can use default implementation of `TextProvider` and can use the code above.